# AngularJS - ng-show not displaying item

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have this inside my controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('app', [], function ($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[%');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%]');
});

myApp.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.show = [];

    // confirmed this returns true when intended
    $scope.showElement = function (id) {
        return ($scope.show.indexOf(id) > -1);
    };
});
```

And my HTML structured as below, with `my-class` using `display: none;` and other rules which are imperative to the display of this element. Because of the number of instances where it is being used I cannot simply remove the class or alter its rules. In all other instances in the application, this works as expected.

```
<div class="my-class" ng-show="showElement(obj.id)">
    ...
</div>
```

The element is not shown on page load, nor is its appearance updated if the underlying variable `$scope.show` is changed.

Comment: Please post more elaborated code. Also, check what does this `hidden` class do.

Comment: The hidden class sets `display: none` and I'm not sure how much more context I'm able to really give. Other aspects of this Angular controller work perfectly fine. This one area is the exception.

Comment: why do you need this class, when you are using `ng-show/hide`, the later would do the job for you. Also, this `hidden` class is the reason you element is not visible, irrespective of `showElement(obj.id)` output.

Comment: This is actually a simpler form of the function being used. I can't express the contents of the function body in a one-liner that can be repeated numerous times. And the CSS class does not inhibit similar controls elsewhere. In those cases `ng-show` still works.

Comment: remove `class="hidden"` and test

Comment: There are other style rules for this class (I've used `hidden` to convey that it affects visibility for this problem), and the class is used in similar control structures in the rest of the app, where, again, it functions correctly.

Comment: I am not sure how the rest of your app is functioning well. But, what I know is, we do not have to explicitly hide the element using `display: none` while using `ng-show / hide`, Angular does the job for us

Comment: I didn't set this up (I would not have used Angular in the first place) so I'm uneasy about changing something that affects 20+ pages.

Comment: Try replacing `hidden` with `ng-hide`, but at the moment you might get [https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig) error

Comment: I already told you I cannot remove the CSS class because there are other rules that are imperative to the display of the element. There is obviously a problem with the controller setup (or Angular itself) and _not_ the CSS class when the CSS class literally causes no problems in any of the 20+ pages where it is being used. I've renamed it to `my-class` here to demonstrate that it is not a simple hiding class. I am not addressing this again.

Comment: Pardon moi for trying to help... You should include the details in the question, and not in the comments so us, the stupid ones, won't make you so annoyed reading only the question and not the whole thread. Open the developer tools and see if you're getting error similar to  [https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig) on the console tab

Comment: There aren't any other details to this. I thought I was giving all that was necessary to resolve this. And I'm not getting that errror; I'm actually getting nothing whatsoever. The element in question is simply not being shown. I'm debugging the function call and it returns the correct values but literally nothing else happens.

Comment: @DissidentRage And when you're just returning `false` from this function (just add `return false;` for debugging purposes), do you see a `ng-hide` class being added to the element?

Comment: There is an `ng-hide` class being added when it evaluates to `false` but it doesn't do anything else when `true`

Comment: @DissidentRage Take a look at [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vspm66xc/) that works fine with your current code, maybe it is something to do with that `my-class` that might override the `display` style after all?

Comment: It already works _everywhere_ else.

Comment: Well if it works everywhere else then you need to take a look at the 
@DissidentRage Well It look like a simple CSS issue, and if the class is only control the `display:none;` style then you can use it in a different way like this updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vspm66xc/2/ but It's impossible to really know what's going on there without a solid reproduction of the bug

Answer (score 0):

The previous development team was manually (by using deep and obfuscated Javascript) adding an additional CSS class in the other instances where it was being used.

My solution was to add a `visible` class using the `ng-class` directive:

```
<div class="my-class" ng-class="{'visible': showElement(obj.id)}">
    ....
</div>
```